# What is the best way to populate select with large json file in terms of speed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I am trying to populate select list with relatively large local json data.
Is this the best way of doing this in terms of speed?

And also when trying to append the options into the select in another way ( the commented out lines ) the code is not working at all - can someone explain to me why is that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  Sickness();
});

function Sickness() {
  let sickness;

  $.getJSON('https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/V1mWAT69Y').done(function(data) {
    sickness = data;

    $('#sickness').html('');
    let sicknessOptions = '';

    $.each(data, function(index, object) {
      $('#sickness').append(`<option value="${object.value}">${object.text}</option>`);

      // sicknessOptions += $(`<option value="${object.value.toUpperCase()}">${object.text.toUpperCase()}</option>`);

    });
    // $('#sickness').append(sicknessOptions);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sickness"></select>
```

Comment: `$(...)` returns a jQuery object. How is this supposed to work when you concatenate it with a string?

Comment: Changing the DOM is slow. Generate the drop-down "outside" the DOM and add it in one piece.

Comment: @Andreas I am sorry that was clearly a dumb mistake. Can you please tell me what do you mean by outside the DOM